# Is j.u.Calendar object immutable/thread-safe in PreparedStatement#setTimestamp, ResultSet#getTimestamp?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm performing some micro optimisations and have noticed that application constructs new j.u.Calendar object on every call of `ResultSet#getTimestamp` or `ResultSet#getTimestamp` like:

```java
Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(name, Calendar.getInstance(UTC));
```

I tried to research whether it is possible to use singleton object and have discovered following:

- H2 driver does not mutate calendar object and consumes the result of  `j.u.Calendar#getTimeZone` call
- PostgreSQL driver behaves similarly to H2
- Oracle driver copies `j.u.Calendar` via `Calendar.getInstance(cal.getTimeZone())` and mutates a copy

So, it seems that j.u.Calendar could be a singleton in case of particular JDBC drivers, but is it true for all JDBC drivers, i.e. are there any specifications/recommendations for driver vendors?

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes. Among their many flaws is mutability. These classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on the legacy classes then. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: @BasilBourque I will try to investigate the where it is possible to use `java.time` classes, however the Q is not about common sense but about micro optimisations, and at first glance using `java.time` is not an option in JDBC domain : application stores all dates in DB using UTC, and the most obvious approach of `rs.getObject(name, Instant.class)` does not work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov JDBC does not define support for `java.time.Instant`. Whether that works is driver-specific behaviour (and some times data-type specific).

Comment: **Search Stack Overflow before posting.** You’ll find much coverage on this: For columns of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use `OffsetDateTime` class in JDBC 4.2 and later. For `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `LocalDateTime`. Never use `Timestamp`, never use `Calendar`.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel [JDBC 4.2](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/jdbc4.2-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1662997579_f335c750613fa400b1c9803803aba823) adds support for `java.time`. Table B-4 specifies that a compliant driver must support `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetTime`, and `OffsetDateTime`. There are no new getters and setters specified. But B-4 requires that the generic getters, the general setters and the general updaters must support the listed `java.time` types.

Comment: @DouglasSurber I am well aware of that, did you mean to address someone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing the JDBC specification says is in the javadoc.

For [`PreparedStatement.setTimestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int,java.sql.Timestamp,java.util.Calendar)) (and similar for `setDate` and `setTime`):

> Sets the designated parameter to the given `java.sql.Timestamp` value,
> using the given `Calendar` object. The driver uses the `Calendar`
> object to construct an SQL `TIMESTAMP` value, which the driver then
> sends to the database. With a `Calendar` object, the driver can
> calculate the timestamp taking into account a custom timezone. [..]

For [`ResultSet.getTimestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp(int,java.util.Calendar)) (and similar for `getDate` and `getTime`):

> [..] This method uses the given calendar to construct an appropriate
> millisecond value for the timestamp if the underlying database does
> not store timezone information.

Both describe the `Calendar` parameter as:

> the `java.util.Calendar` object to use in constructing the timestamp

In other words, JDBC implementations are allowed to "use" the calendar object in any way they deem fit. Some JDBC implementations actually use this calendar instance to perform calculations, others just extract the time zone data and do their calculations in another way (including, but not limited to, creating a new `Calendar` instance).

In other words, do not assume that it is safe to reuse the `Calendar` object across multiple threads. Using it across multiple invocations in the same thread is probably safe, but even that could be a dangerous assumption (e.g. you may want to reset the time zone with `setTimeZone`). However, it would be better to simply not use it at all, and instead switch to using `LocalDateTime`, which foregoes time zone manipulation, or - assuming the column is actually a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, `OffsetDateTime`.

I would also be wary of making optimizations targeting the behaviour of a specific driver. If the implementation of the driver changes, you could suddenly be faced with a hard to diagnose issues like wrong timestamp values caused by race-condition/incorrect shared use of the `Calendar`.

Comment: so, the best way is to define a set of strategies how to read `Instant` from DB and allow application developer to pick up the most suitable/optimal one?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I'd suggest that your starting point should be to limit it to the data types defined in JDBC (`java.time.Instant` support is not specified in JDBC). A `TIMESTAMP` (`TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`) is tied to a `LocalDateTime`, while a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is tied to a `OffsetDateTime`. Conversion from a `LocalDateTime` to an `Instant` is ambiguous (what time zone is its base), which is one of the major issues with the way `java.sql.Timestamp` was defined.

Comment: I'm not designing new application, goal is to improve existing one, application stores dates in UTC (columns are backed up by either DATE or TIMESTAMP in order to not depend on DB operating system or patches), and the real Q is: "what is the best way to get `Instant` from resultset". I got your point that getting `Instant` via `LocalDateTime` could make sense (actually I can't believe, cause the "final goal" is to just get long from resultset, moreover, PostgreSQL driver fails to convert `DATE` type to `LocalDateTime`, however it does not experiencing any difficulties with rs. getTimestamp())

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov A `DATE` is mapped to `LocalDate`, that said, JDBC does specify conversions for `DATE` and `LocalDateTime` (though technically only for set operations (see table B-5 in JDBC 4.3)), but the expectation is that if `setObject` works for a type, then so should `getObject(int/String, Class<T>)`.

Comment: In that case I don't see any point to suggest using `rs.getObject(,LocalDate(Time).class)` - that is unreliable. `rs.getTimestamp()` gives application a chance to interpret incoming data on it's own way, while `rs.getObject(,LocalDate(Time).class)` throws exceptions just because the behaviour was not mentioned in spec or driver vendor didn't anticipate some useful cases, yours "JDBC does specify conversions for" actually means that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov If you're writing a framework, you should inspect the `ResultSetMetaData` or `ParameterMetaData` to infer type information to use the right method. In any case, if the driver currently support `getTimestamp(..)`, but doesn't support `getObject(.., LocalDateTime.class)` on that same column, I'd consider that a driver bug in general.

Comment: Mark, I would appreciate if you were adding your last thoughts to the A.